# How to generate combination of a sequence?

Tags: design-patterns, combinations

I want to generate a combination froma sequence. For example if the sequence is "AbBCd" then the output will be 
A
b
B
C
d
Ab
bB
BC
Cd
AbB
bBC
BCd
AbBC
bBCd
AbBCd

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "ABCD";
        String prefix = "";
        combination(prefix, str);
    }

    public static void combination(String prefix, String str) {

        System.out.println(prefix);

        for (int i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
            combination(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(i+1));

    }

}
```